# Databound Focus Control Attached Property only running once

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, focus, attached-properties

I'm trying to set focus on a textbox, and it does work the first time.  But when I set Editable to true afterwards, the SetControlFocus.OnSetFocusChanged does not run again.

Here's the code that I've been using for the attached property:

```
public class SetControlFocus
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SetFocusProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SetFocus",
                                                                           typeof(Boolean),
                                                                           typeof(SetControlFocus),
                                                                           new PropertyMetadata(false, OnSetFocusChanged));

    private static void OnSetFocusChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d != null && d is UIElement)
        {
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                (d as UIElement).GotFocus += OnLostFocus;
                (d as UIElement).Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                (d as UIElement).GotFocus -= OnLostFocus;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != null && sender is UIElement)
        {
            (sender as UIElement).SetValue(SetFocusProperty, false);
        }
    }

    public static Boolean GetSetFocus(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return (Boolean)target.GetValue(SetFocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSetFocus(DependencyObject target, Boolean value)
    {
        target.SetValue(SetFocusProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Here is the textbox binding on the form's XAML:

```
<TextBox ExternEvents:SetControlFocus.SetFocus="{Binding SetFocused}" Visibility="{Binding IsEditableVis}" Text="{Binding Body}" />
```

And here is the code in the viewmodel:

```
    public bool SetFocused
    {
        get { return m_IsEditable; }
    }

    private bool m_IsEditable;

    public bool IsEditable
    {
        get { return m_IsEditable; }
        set
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanging("IsEditable");
            m_IsEditable = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsEditable");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SetFocused");
        }
    }
```

As for how I'm testing this, I have an ordinary button hooked up that alternates between setting IsEditable to true and false.  When IsEditable is false, the textbox is hidden, causing it to lose focus.

When stepping through the debugger, the following steps occur the first time:

- Step into **setter** of IsEditable
- **Property Changing** Notification for "IsEditable"
- m_IsEditable **set to true**
- **Property Changed** Notification for "IsEditable"
- **Property Changed** Notification for "SetFocused"
- Step into **getter** of SetFocused, returns true.
- **Call** SetControlFocus.OnSetFocusChanged
- **Attach event** OnLostFocus for GotFocus
- **Run** UIElement.Focus()
- **Run** SetControlFocus.OnLostFocus(...)
- **Detach event** OnLostFocus event
- **return** from SetControlFocus.OnSetFocusChanged
- **return** from setter of IsEditable

The second and subsequent times, SetControlFocus and the getter are not called:

- Step into **setter** of IsEditable
- **Property Changing** Notification for "IsEditable"
- m_IsEditable **set to true**
- **Property Changed** Notification for "IsEditable"
- **Property Changed** Notification for "SetFocused"
- **return** from setter of IsEditable

I can't figure out what's causing this to happen.  I've tried setting the binding to Two-Way as well as setting various combinations of m_IsEditable and IsEditable to false, but this behavior does not change.  I believe that I will be able to set focus on the controls if I can at least call the attached property's SetControlFocus again.

Any ideas what I can reset so that SetControlFocus will work every time I set IsEditable to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried changing the binding to Two-Way again, this time it seems to be working.